# Plot a 3D volume in PGFplots using something akin to maximum intensity projection

Tags: pgfplots

I have a function $\rho(x, y, z) = e^{-|x|}$, which I'd like to plot.  It yields a 3d volume - I've already plotted it in Julia (using Makie.jl), and it looks like this:

[image: Makie.jl function visualization]

I'd like to be able to plot something like this in PGFplots.  I've come up with a quite 'hacky' solution, which works, but I would of course prefer something better.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  colormap/viridis,
  colorbar,
  xlabel = {$x$},
  ylabel = {$y$},
  zlabel = {$z$},
  title = {$\rho = e^{-|x|}$}
  ]

\addplot3 [
          scatter,
          only marks,
          mark = cube*,
          opacity = {0.175*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/2000},
          % mesh/ordering = x varies,
          point meta = {exp(-abs(x))}
] table {data.dat};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where `data.dat` is simply columns of x, y, and z in a cube.

```
x    y    z
-3.0 -3.0 -3.0
-3.0 -3.0 -2.9
[...]
3.0   3.0  3.0
```

My current visualization looks like this.
[image]

Is there any way I can make the PGFplots visualization better?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but your second solution (which you say "works") is not a maximum intensity projection in my view. What is the purpose of your figure? How strictly should we understand "something akin to"?

Comment: @bers - my idea making this was to showcase that the density varied as a function of x, and nothing else - and also to communicate how that looks and how a symmetry argument can be used in such a situation.  Anything which communicates that is fine by me :)

Comment: I feel one way to achieve what you are seeking is to indicate y-z Slices. I am thinking plotting continuous colors in y and z, then along x add thin separators (like grid lines on the outside of your plotting rectangle) between different x values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Nice question! How about

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=-2.6,xmax=2.5,ymin=-5,ymax=5.1,zmin=0.78,zmax=1.2,
  colormap/viridis,
  colorbar,
  xlabel = {$x$},
  ylabel = {$y$},
  zlabel = {$z$},
  title = {$\rho = e^{-|x|}$}
  ]
%\pgfplotsi
\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{0}
\fill[mapped color] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}+0.01) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}+0.01) 
-- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax}-0.01) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax}-0.01)  -- cycle;
\fill[mapped color] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}+0.01) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}+0.01) 
-- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax}-0.01) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax}-0.01)  -- cycle;
\fill[mapped color] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}+0.01) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}+0.01) 
-- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}-0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}+0.01) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}+0.01,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}+0.01)  -- cycle;
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-25,-24,...,25}{
 \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,samples=2,samples y=2,domain=0.8:1.2,domain y=-5:5,
           opacity = {0.5*exp(-3*abs(#1/25))},
           point meta = {exp(-abs(#1/25))}
 ] (#1/25,y,x);
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play with it. If you e.g. change the opacity function to

```
 opacity = {0.5*exp(-5*abs(#1/25))},
```

you get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Though it solves my present use case, I suspect I'll have to similarly hack any other 'volume' plot I might need to make :)

Comment: @AnshulSinghvi If there is a general systematic in these one can write a style that does all the work. I made it a bit more user-friendly by using pgfkeys. But without knowing what the general situation is it is hard to make things more general.